# Calculation Of Steel Beam

Tags: beam, steel, load

I have a project where I need to span a 6 meter gap (~ 19.5ft)

The beam will be supporting a load of 150KG (~ 330lbs)

The load will be evenly spread along the beam.

There can be no supports along the beams length.

Does anyone know how to calculate the dimensions of the beam required, a small amount of deflection is ok but certainly do not want it sagging significantly.

Comment: What _kind_ of load will it be supporting? Is this a static load or could it be dynamic (like a roof where snow might pile on it or a support for a chain hoist where the load could change or move)? I don't know all the things necessary to go into such a calculation, but the little bit you've provided just doesn't feel like it's enough.

Comment: HI It is indeed a roof structure, snow here is negligible not a huge concern, I have factored in a good chunk of extra load to cover this.

Comment: Does your project require a building permit?  If so, they AHJ will likely require plans that are stamped by an engineer (i.e. a PE) or architect.  So even if you do properly calculate the correct beam size, your word will not be sufficient.

Comment: No permit required for this project so keeps thing simple, just wanted to make sure I bought the right material :)

Answer (score 1):

### Please consult a structural engineer if you are uncertain about what you are doing. The consequence can be severe.

**Determine beam size (using the allowable stress method)**

fa = 0.6Fy = 0.6x36 = 21.6 ksi for A36 steel. fa = 30 ksi for A50 steel.

M = wL^2/8 (kips-ft or lbs-ft)

Sx = M/fa (in^3)

Fy = yield strength of the steel (ksi)

fa = allowable bending stress (ksi)

M = simply support beam moment

w = uniformly distributed load = 1.2*Total Load/Span Length (L), the factor 1.2 represents a 20% allowance for the weight of the steel beam. Revise after a beam size is selected, w = (total load/L) + ws, ws = unit weight of the steel beam (lb/ft)

Sx = section modulus of the steel beam

You can determine the size of the steel beam using the steel table that lists the size of the beam (b x d) and its corresponding section modulus (Sx).

**Estimate the live load deflection**

Midspan Deflection d' = 5*w*L^4/384*E*I

w = total load/L

E = Young's Modulus = 29000 ksi

I = moment of inertia (in^4), see steel table for the selected beam.

Ideally, the deflection should not exceed L/360. Chose a deeper beam if it exceeds the limit.

Comment: So that deflection limit is valid for the OP's location?

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, it is quite typical, unless you have something delicate above that is susceptible to deflection, but it appears not in the OP's concerns.

Comment: Thank you for that response, I shall try and get my head round it after work, much appreciated.

Comment: I moved the warning to the top to emphasize it.

Comment: Watch out for unit conversion. 1 ksi = 1000 lbs, 1 ft = 12", the resulting deflection shall be in inches.